# Hosting multiple projects on same domain but different path

Tags: linux, angular, server, apache2, hosting

May be this question has been asked, but cannot find any solution, hence I am posting this myself.

I have a website example.com which is pointing to a folder, say `example/project_name1/dist1`. Now, what I want is to point to a different folder `example/project_name2/dist2` when I access domain example.com/admin. How this can be achieved?

Server is `apache2 on linux`. Projects are built with `Angular4`.

Comment: pl. check it says: software tools commonly used by programmers.

Comment: @jww If you don't understand please do not intervene, Question is absolutely correct and is of development.
People like you who just comment everywhere just to increase their points are the real problem of this world.
PS. First, learn the scope of any Software project lifecycle. Talk to your production team about this question, they will let you know is it right or not.